# MultipartMemoryStream in Dot Net Core

Tags: angularjs, .net-core, multipartform-data

I have a .Net 4.5.2 App that I am moving to Dot Net Core. This app allows the user to upload a file with Metadata (Angular Client Side) and the Api will handle the request and process the file. Here is the existing code that does that.

**Api**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("AskQuestions")]
public void ProvideClarifications(int id)
{
  var user = base.GetUserLookup();
  if (user != null)
  {
    var streamProvider = new MultiPartStreamProvider();
    IEnumerable<HttpContent> parts = null;
    Task.Factory
        .StartNew(() => parts = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).Result.Contents,
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
            TaskScheduler.Default)
        .Wait();

        // do some stuff with streamProvider.FormData
  }
}
```

**Provider to Handle File and MetaData**

```
public class MultiPartStreamProvider : MultipartMemoryStreamProvider
{
    private string _originalFileName = string.Empty;
    public Dictionary<string, object> FormData { get; set; }

    public byte[] ByteStream { get; set; }

    public string FileName
    {
        get
        {
            return _originalFileName.Replace("\"", "");
        }
    }
    public MultiPartStreamProvider()
    {
        this.FormData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
    public override Task ExecutePostProcessingAsync()
    {
        foreach (var content in Contents)
        {
            var contentDispo = content.Headers.ContentDisposition;
            var name = UnquoteToken(contentDispo.Name);

            if (name.Contains("file"))
            {
                _originalFileName = UnquoteToken(contentDispo.FileName);
                this.ByteStream = content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
            }
            else
            {
                var val = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                this.FormData.Add(name, val);
            }
        }
        return base.ExecutePostProcessingAsync();
    }
    private static string UnquoteToken(string token)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
        {
            return token;
        }

        if (token.StartsWith("\"", StringComparison.Ordinal) && token.EndsWith("\"", StringComparison.Ordinal) && token.Length > 1)
        {
            return token.Substring(1, token.Length - 2);
        }

        return token;
    }
}
static class FormDataExtensions {
    public static Object GetObject(this Dictionary<string, object> dict, Type type)
    {
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        foreach (var kv in dict)
        {
            var prop = type.GetProperty(kv.Key);
            if (prop == null) continue;

            object value = kv.Value;
            var targetType = IsNullableType(prop.PropertyType) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) : prop.PropertyType;

            if (value is Dictionary<string, object>)
            {
                value = GetObject((Dictionary<string, object>)value, prop.PropertyType); // <= This line                   
            }
            value = Convert.ChangeType(value, targetType);
            prop.SetValue(obj, value, null);
        }
        return obj;
    }
    public static T GetObject<T>(this Dictionary<string, object> dict)
    {
        return (T)GetObject(dict, typeof(T));
    }
    private static bool IsNullableType(Type type)
    {
        return type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>));
    }
}
```

So this works totally fine targeting framework, but in Core I get an exception on this line

> .StartNew(() => parts = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).Result.Contents,

**Exception**

> 'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What do I need to make sure I can get this file and metadata? Is there a way in Core of getting HttpContent from a HttpRequest

Answer (score 6):

Asp.Net Core has support for multipart file uploads built-in. The model binding component will make this available when you have a `List<IFormFile>` parameter.

See the [docs on file uploads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads) for more details, here is the relevant example it gives for handling multipart uploads:

> ```
> [HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
> public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
> {
>     long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);
>
>     // full path to file in temp location
>     var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
>
>     foreach (var formFile in files)
>     {
>         if (formFile.Length > 0)
>         {
>             using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
>             {
>                 await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     // process uploaded files
>     // Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.
>
>     return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath});
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this, so I can use something like Request.Form.Files to get this as well? I am sending a file along with metadata that I need to access from Request.Form

Comment: @MartinUllrich is there a reason you are processing the files sequentially synchronous, instead of awaiting all the tasks at once?

Comment: Ah, looks like it won't make much difference currently because everything will be bottle necked at the the HDD.  But, why are you saving all of the files to the same location?

Comment: @johnny5 you're right, it looks weird. this is meant to be a quote from the docs, the sample is taken from the linked docs site. I'll contact one of the authors of this doc page.

Comment: There are some overhauls to the doc already in progress: https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/5331

Comment: Thanks Martin, I’m just hoping no one is using this in production code, but then again if they are they should have tested better